# "Generation of designer file failed" when adding custom ExpressionBuilder tags to .ascx

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp.net-3.5, ascx, expressionbuilder

I am making some changes to a user control (.ascx file) in my ASP.NET 3.5 web application project in Visual Studio 2008.  I noticed that the changes I was making in the markup were not being reflected in the designer file (a fairly [well-known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45325/how-do-you-force-visual-studio-to-regenerate-the-designer-files-for-aspx-ascx-f) [problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/128202d7-5ecb-4921-8ac3-e173d4824235/)).  I tried deleting the designer file and regenerating it using "Convert to Web Application."  On doing so, I got this error:

> Generation of designer file failed: Could not load type
>   'MyWebApplication.MyCustomExpressionBuilder' from assembly
>   'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   (E:\MyPath\MyWebApplication\Web.config line 166)

The change I was making in the .ascx markup was to use a [custom `ExpressionBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.expressionbuilder(v=vs.90).aspx) as the value of the `Visible` and/or `Enabled` properties of certain controls within my .ascx.  This particular `ExpressionBuilder` is successfully used elsewhere in the web application to return Boolean values to similar properties.  For example:

```
<asp:TableRow runat="server" Visible="<%$ MyCustom: TheExpressionValue %>">
    <%-- some TableCells and contents here --%>
</asp:TableRow>
```

The Web.config line noted in the error message is the `add` tag in the following:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true">
        <!-- Skipping the 'assemblies' and 'buildProviders' areas -->
        <expressionBuilders>
            <add expressionPrefix="MyCustom" type="MyWebApplication.MyCustomExpressionBuilder" />
        </expressionBuilders>
    </compilation>
    <!-- other stuff -->
</system.web>
```

The class `MyCustomExpressionBuilder` is in the same web application project in a directory called `Code` (not `App_Code`, for whatever reason, and I'm not sure how much will break if I move the class file).

I can work around this issue if I have to by avoiding the custom `ExpressionBuilder` in the control and adding some properties for the calling page to use instead, but that would not be ideal.  Note that built-in expressions (like `<%$ Resources: CommonResource, SomeTextString %>`) were already in the control and were working fine.

Here are some things I have tried:

1. Just rebuilding the project.  The designer file does not load, and I get lots of build errors in the code-behind due to missing properties.
2. Just changing the control markup, saving, and changing the control back (before I tried deleting the designer file), making sure that I did not have the designer file open.  This process just failed silently.
3. Adding the `ClassName` parameter to my `<%@ Control %>` directive, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766/generation-of-designer-file-failed).  No effect.
4. Adding `<%@ Assembly Name="MyWebApplication" %>`.  No effect.
5. Adding `<%@ Import Namepace="MyWebApplication" %>`.  No effect.
6. Adding `<%@ Reference VirtualPath="~/Code/MyCustomExpressionBuilder.cs" %>`.  No effect.
7. Closing and restarting Visual Studio.  On the first attempt to run "Convert to Web Application" on the ascx, at least I got a different error: "Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown."  After attempting to rebuild the project and getting all the errors (see #1 above), "Convert to Web Application" produces the same "Generation of designer file failed" error message as before.

Upgrading the project to a new Visual Studio version is not currently an option.  As mentioned earlier, I would prefer not to move the custom `ExpressionBuilder` class, since it is working at least from .aspx files.  What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The issue is that, for some reason, the compiler cannot find the assembly with the custom `ExpressionBuilder`.  What fixed the problem was to use a [Partial Assembly Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0a7zy9z5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) with slightly more information than just the class name and namespace in the `add` tag:

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true">
    <!-- Skipping the 'assemblies' and 'buildProviders' areas -->
    <expressionBuilders>
        <add expressionPrefix="MyCustom" type="MyWebApplication.MyCustomExpressionBuilder, MyWebApplication" />
    </expressionBuilders>
</compilation>
<!-- other stuff -->
```

In other words, change the `type` attribute to specify both the class name (with namespace) and the name of the assembly.  Note that specifying any more additional information causes a different error (even the version number, and even if the version number is correct).

As to how I found out, a good tip for solving these problems is to enable logging as described [here](http://davidovitz.blogspot.com/2007/11/understanding-of-designer-file-failed.html).  For VS2008, you would use `regedit` to:

1. Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0`
2. Create a new key named `WebApplicationProjects` if it does not exist.  Then, select it.
3. Create a new key named `Debug` if it does not exist.  Then, select it.
4. Add a new string called `LogFile`.  The value should be a path to which VS2008 will have write permissions (so, potentially not a file in the root of C:).  Make sure to escape any backslashes, like `C:\\PathICanWrite\\vslogfile.txt`.
5. Add a new DWORD called `Enabled`, and set it to 1.
6. Add a new DWORD called `LogFieldGeneratorFailures`, and set it to 1.
7. Restart VS2008.

When I looked at the log file, I was able to use the stack trace to determine that I had an assembly load problem, which now seems obvious.  A message in the log gives a further tip to resolve assembly load issues:

> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
>   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
>   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

I found that I needed to restart the machine for the new registry setting to take effect.  Then, additional assembly binding information was available in the log.